# Delete Rows tool calls local pathway instead of data store scratch pathway

Tags: arcgis-server, geoprocessing-service, warning-000117

Publishing ETL's as services for automation and using the Delete Rows tool runs successfully in desktop. Publish the results and when the service is run the Delete Rows tool is trying to make the edits to the local pathway instead of the service generated job pathway and actual location of the table. Run the identical process over a dozen times on other models using the Delete Feature tool and not had this problem but I can't find where/why the Delete Row tool isn't calling the table from the correct pathway.

The process flow is take the SQL.sde connection and create a timestamp version, change versions to now use the timestamp version instead of DBO.DEFAULT, within the timestamped version call the table and delete the rows from the table.

**This is the messaging generated when the process is run from desktop and successfully is completed, verified table data and tracking to confirm.**

```
Executing (CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput): CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput C:\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde DBO.DEFAULT C:\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:21:18 2014
Running script CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput...
Completed script CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput...
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:21:20 2014 (Elapsed Time: 2.63 seconds) Executing (ChangeVersionTableInput): ChangeVersionTableInput C:\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS WGIS_ETL_20140917_102118 C:\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:21:20 2014
Running script ChangeVersionTableInput...
Completed script ChangeVersionTableInput...
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:21:23 2014 (Elapsed Time: 2.95 seconds) Executing (Delete Rows (2)): DeleteRows C:\Users\sfierro\AppData\Local\Temp\20\arcC687\scratch\WGIS_ETL_20140917_102118.sde\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:21:24 2014
WARNING 000117: Warning empty output generated.
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:21:30 2014 (Elapsed Time: 6.84 seconds) Executing (Append (3)): Append in_memory\ELLISTable
```

**This is the messaging when run as a published service**

```
Executing (CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput): CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput \\dotstor01\ArcServer_Data-Tst\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde DBO.DEFAULT \\dotstor01\ArcServer_Data-Tst\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:34:00 2014
Running script CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput...
Completed script CreateTimeStampVersionTableInput...
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:34:01 2014 (Elapsed Time: 1.11 seconds) Executing (ChangeVersionTableInput): ChangeVersionTableInput \\dotstor01\ArcServer_Data-Tst\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS WGIS_ETL_20140917_103400 \\dotstor01\ArcServer_Data-Tst\arcgisserver\ETL_Scripts\ToolData\ODOT_SDE.sde
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:34:01 2014
Running script ChangeVersionTableInput...
Completed script ChangeVersionTableInput...
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:34:02 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.90 seconds) Executing (Delete Rows (2)): DeleteRows C:\Users\agstst\AppData\Local\Temp\tims_etls\ellisemailtesting9_gpserver\jd18f572aab884c1fa23145d8032f6ad5\scratch\scratch.gdb\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS
Start Time: Wed Sep 17 10:34:02 2014
Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:34:02 2014 (Elapsed Time: 0.09 seconds) Succeeded at Wed Sep 17 10:34:03 2014 (Elapsed Time: 5 minutes 34 seconds)
```

If you look at the processing time for the Delete Rows its 0.09 seconds as a service compared with 6.84 from desktop and messaging returns it succeeded but messaging shows it killed the rest of the model and never did the append or several other steps after this Delete Rows occurs. Review of the table confirms that not a single record was deleted.

**The issue lies in the tool trying to hit a table from**  C:\Users\agstst\AppData\Local\Temp\tims_etls\ellisemailtesting9_gpserver\jd18f572aab884c1fa23145d8032f6ad5\scratch\scratch.gdb\GIS.TIMS.WGIS_ELLIS

**that does not exist and the actual table exists at**
\dotstor01\ArcServer_Data-Tst\arcgisserver\directories\arcgisjobs\tims_etls\ellisemailtesting9_gpserver\jd18f572aab884c1fa23145d8032f6ad5\scratch\scratch.gdb\GIS.TIMS.WGIS.ELLIS

I attempted to go against everything I have read and specified the scratchworkspace for just the Delete Rows tool as %scratchFolder% thinking that might get the service to route to the data store job specific scratch but it didn't. I have removed the tool and rebuilt it in just to eliminate cached results from testing could be ruled out. I'm not sure how else to properly get this 1 tool to route correctly.